# User Login Redirect

Tags: redirect, elementor

I am trying to redirect a user to the referring page after they login.  I have tried multiple different css and for whatever reason I can't get it to work.

I am using Elementor - so not sure if this is the problem.  I am very novice, like must read each line of code very slowly.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: CSS (cascading style sheets) apply styles to alter your website's appearance.   There is no way to use CSS to redirect.  Did you mean that you tried JavaScript (js)?   Elementor appears to be a WordPress plugin, so maybe you should be using PHP?   Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.